# Show a menu of actions when rick-clicking on a row using React Data Table Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menu, right-click, react-data-table-component

I am using this Data Table React component: https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/docs/getting-started-intro--docs

And i need to make a feature that when the user right click on a table row, it needs to show a list of actions that the user can click and run some code

I searched all over the internet but cannot find anything useful, can anybody help, please?

I tried searchig for a lot of solutions. Tried search if the react-contextify can help but cannot find something that can help me. Not even in the docs of the component i'm using